Angular filter formArray controls based on some condition
I'm facing one issue I want to filter formArray controls
public checklistForm!: FormGroup;

 this.checklistForm = this.fb.group({
      checklistItems: this.fb.array([])
 });

// some logic

  public checklistItems(): FormArray {
    return this.checklistForm.get('checklistItems') as FormArray;
  }

// filter some checklistsItems
const newFormArray = this.checklistItems().value.filter(// some condition, may be check of id) //this return an array  

HTML
<div *ngFor="let checkList of checklistItems().controls; let checkListIndex=index"></div>

I'm not sure how can I filter this checklistItems().controls

ad *ngIf condition inside your div
`<div *ngFor="let checkList of checklistItems().controls; let checkListIndex=index">
<ng-container *ngIf="some condition">
// your code

`
@DaksheshBaldaniya How can i do in TS file, I need to write some logic for filtering out values based on multiple conditions

We can just use the filter to store the values in a temporary variable, which we will use to run the *ngFor below is a working example, where I filter the form controls based on search.
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { Component, inject } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ReactiveFormsModule,
  FormArray,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
  FormBuilder,
} from '@angular/forms';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import 'zone.js';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  template: `
  Search: <input #input (input)="search(input.value)"/>
  <form [formGroup]="checklistForm">
    <div formArrayName="checklistItems">
      <div *ngFor="let checkList of filteredCheckListItems; let checkListIndex=index" [formGroupName]="checkListIndex">
        {{checkListIndex}}
        <input type="text" [formControl]="checkList.controls.test" id="test" name="test"/>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
  {{checklistForm.value | json}}
  `,
})
export class App {
  fb = inject(FormBuilder);
  public checklistForm!: FormGroup;
  filteredCheckListItems: Array<any> = [];

  // some logica

  public checklistItems(): FormArray {
    return this.checklistForm.get('checklistItems') as FormArray;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.checklistForm = this.fb.group({
      checklistItems: this.fb.array([]),
    });
    const checkListItems = this.checklistItems();
    checkListItems.push(this.fb.group({ test: new FormControl('apple') }));
    checkListItems.push(this.fb.group({ test: new FormControl('banana') }));
    checkListItems.push(this.fb.group({ test: new FormControl('grapes') }));

    // store the full unfiltered checklist items in the variable
    this.filteredCheckListItems = this.checklistItems().controls;
  }

  search(searchStr: string) {
    console.log(searchStr);
    this.filteredCheckListItems = (<Array<FormGroup>>(
      this.checklistItems().controls
    )).filter((item: FormGroup) => {
      return item?.controls?.['test']?.value?.includes(searchStr);
    });
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);

Stackblitz Demo

This solved one issue and created another one. I made a stackblitz to demonstrate and see if you can help. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-epgb4pls?file=src%2Fmain.ts when you filter it selects random inputs

@Merv what is the other issue please replicate on stackblitz and share

I already know what seemed to be the problem!! I have no idea why but using [formcontrol] instead of formcontrolname (which im using in my entire project) fixed the problem. maybe its a bug? If you know why please explain. thx for quick responses. https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-epgb4pls?file=src%2Fmain.ts now it should work like I intend to. (btw the @ tag to mention u is not working or im doing it wrong)
